# Deriving WKB approximation step query

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I am working through the derivation of the WKB approximation and I can't seem to work out how one of the steps is done.  I've provided a picture from my lecture notes.

[Screenshot for Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE4dV.png)

How do they manage to obtain $Y_{1}=-\frac{1}{2}\log{Y_{0}}$ from the previous equation? I have tried working it out and haven't been able to reach the value provided.

Answer (score 0):

They showed $Y_{1}' = - \frac{1}{2} \frac{Y_{0}''}{Y_{0}'}$.  Note that $\frac{Y_{0}''}{Y_{0}'} = \left( \log(Y_{0}') \right)'$.  Hence $Y_{1}' = -\frac{1}{2} \left(\log(Y_{0}')\right)'$ and the fundamental theorem of calculus gives $Y_{1} = - \frac{1}{2} \log(Y_{0}') + C$ for some $C \in \mathbb{R}$.  (It seems, in your attachment, they have the freedom to set $C = 0$.)